# How do I add a Hubspot tracking code into a Drupal Website

Tags: blocks

I followed the instructions for Drupal lower on this page: https://knowledge.hubspot.com/getting-started-with-hubspot-v2/install-the-tracking-code

by adding a block and doing exactly what they said to do. But the tracking code ends up showing up on the Footer of the website but should be hidden.

What am I doing wrong? Do you have other instructions that would work better?

Comment: If you're using CKEditor, click the "source" button first, then paste the code and make sure you select FULL HTML as your text filter.

Comment: Won't script tags still be stripped out?

Comment: There is also a module for this. https://www.drupal.org/project/hubspot